# Weird drain design?

Tags: shower, drainage

I recently moved into a new house and we quickly noticed weird smells coming from the shower drain. After taking the plug out we noticed the drain has space for water to pool at the bottom without draining, and this is collecting bacteria and detritus. I've done a quick diagram to show what I mean. I don't think it's to create a barrier between the shower and the sewer because the hole leading to the sewer is left uncovered. Is this normal? It seems like it would cause more hassle to clean and I'm not sure what the benefit would be.

[image]
[image]

Thanks for your time!

[image: Poorly done paint diagram of drain]

Comment: Can you get a photo - we might be able to establish whether someone actually went to the trouble of constructing their own trap design, rather than just buy one off a shelf - vs, they left a component out accidentally.

Comment: Hi, I've added a couple of photos to the post, one with all the components

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a debris trap.   It should catch some or most hair, lint, jewelry, stones, etc.  It lifts out easily and is designed to be cleaned regularly by users, not plumbers.

There should also be a regular trap beneath the floor.

The smell might be due to:

- Nobody has cleaned this in a while.  It should be cleaned regularly.
- There is no trap under the floor
- The trap under the floor is dry from disuse.

Looking at your second photo I think the thing is quite a clever design.  If I'm not reading too much into it I think what you have is actually as follows, two debris traps and a gas trap:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I think you might be right. Issue is trap 1 doesn't seem to be removable but I think that was due to how it was installed. Definitely something I can follow up on, cheers!

Comment: If i've got it right, trap 1 is the right hand thing of the two things you removed in your second picture.  So is removable.  Trap 2 is what we're looking down into in your first picture.  What I drew as the opening on the left side of trap 1 is the four slits in the plastic cup thingy in your photo.  There also seems to be another bit that protrudes *into* trap 1, from the bottom of the cap, that I didn't draw.  Can you figure out what that's for?

Answer (score 1):

That design is that of a floor drain, not a shower drain.

The reservoir that you have marked in green and blue is made so if there is any debris that could possibly clog the line, will get trapped in the lower portion and not go down the pipe, potentially clogging it. These types of drains usually have an easy to remove grate, so it can be lifted and the debris removed easily